# select only condition form the ternary operator using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on the C#, trying to fetch condition from the Ternary Operator.
I tried regex pattern

> `\(\s*\w+.+?(?=\?)\s*\?`

but in some cases, it matches perfectly but in some cases, it matches wrong conditions.

> ```
> `MatchCollection mcCollection = Regex.Matches(sInputLine, @"\(\s*\w+.+?(?=\?)\s*\?");`
> ```

**sInputLine line like:-**

1. string result = x > y ? "x is greater than y" : "No result";
2. string result = x > y ? "x is greater than y" : x < y ? "x is less than y" : x == y ? "x is equal to y" : "No result";
3. xyz.pqr((!"0".equals(x > y ? "x is greater than y" : "No result");
4. string Abc = ((string)Array[0]==null? "":(string)Array[0]) + " " + ((string)Array[1]==null? "":(string)Array[1]);

**from this input lines matching strings should be like below**

from input line 1

```
 1. x > y ?
```

from input line 2

```
 2. x > y ?
    x < y ?
    x == y ?
```

from input line 3

```
 3. x > y ?
```

from input line 4

```
 4. (string)Array[0]==null?
    (string)Array[1]==null?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(\(|(?<!=)=)(?<target>(\(\w*\))?([^(]|(?<=)=)*?\?)
```

matches all your examples.
The `(string)Array...` is complicated with the double `=` allowed here and the opened and closed brackets.

If you want to exclude the `?` and spaces in front of it just exclude it from the target group:

```
(\(|(?<!=)=)(?<target>(\(\w*\))?([^(]|(?<=)=)*?) *\?
```

- `(\(|(?<!=)=)` a leading ( or =, but no == (= with negative lookahead to =)
- `(?<target>` group named 'target'
- `(\(\w*\))?` a possible item in brackets, i.e. (string), (int32), (ab12)
- `([^(]|(?<=)=)*?` characters that are not ( or a single =
- `\?)` a ? in the end, end of target group